# The click() method in JavaScript isn't working for the search in google maps

Tags: javascript

I typed in the following code into the inspector:

```
$('.tactile-searchbox-input').value = 'byu store'
$('.searchbox-searchbutton').click()
```

It was able to put in 'byu store' into google maps search bar but it didn't successfully click on the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` event will not properly trigger the Google Maps search functionality unless the `keyup` event has already occurred. So we can manually trigger a `keyup` event after updating the value.

```
$('#searchboxinput').value = 'byu store';
$('#searchboxinput').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('keyup'));
$('#searchbox-searchbutton').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Get it by ID:

```
$('#searchbox-searchbutton').click()
```

Comment: $('.tactile-searchbox-input').value = 'byu store'
$('#searchbox-searchbutton').click() It showed the same results as calling the class. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I just tested it and it worked. You can try to use `document.getElementById('searchbox-searchbutton').click()` tho.